# Command Line "print to XPS" from MS WORD

Tags: command-line, microsoft-word, printing, xps

I need a command line to save/print/export existing Microsoft Word as XPS files. something like...

```
C:\> print c:\Documents\MyDoc.docx > D:\Repository\MyDoc.xps
```

The question involves: PC machines (Windows 7), Microsoft Word (2007) and XPS

I'm working on a production floor - I cannot install new software on these machines.

Regards,
S.C.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no such option.
One can load a document with a macro that does this - but no CLI...
If you want to try it (from excel, at least) - use the following macro as an autostart:
 `Sub save2XPS()
'
' save2XPS Macro
' Save file to XPS
'
'
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypeXPS, Filename:= _
        "C:\Certificate of Calibration.xps", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
    
End Sub`